# Changing the font of the selected text in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextview

I'm trying to create a custom “Change font” NSPopupButton for a Mac App (not an iOS App). I can detect a change in font selection:

```
long fontItemIndex = [fontPopup indexOfSelectedItem];
NSMenuItem *fontItem = [fontPopup itemAtIndex:(int)selectedFontItemIndex];
NSString *fontName = [selectedFontItem title];
```

Given this NSString of a font name, I cannot seem to find out how to actually change the selected text in my NSTextView `textView` to this new font.

I'm simply dazzled by the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFontManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004043): it seems `convertFont:toFamily:` is what I need. When I do this:

```
NSFont *font = [NSFont fontWithName:fontName size:12.0];
[textView setFont:font];
```

It sets all text in the text view, not just the selected text. But when I do this:

```
NSFontManager *fontManager = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
[fontManager convertFont:[fontManager selectedFont] toFamily:fontName];
```

it doesn't do a thing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside a `NSTextView` is a `NSTextStorage` (a subclass of `NSAttributedString`) and you’ll have to modify the attribute named `NSFontAttributeName`.

First get the range where you want to change the font attribute:

```
NSRange selection = textView.selectedRange;
```

Now add the font attribute to the selection:

```
NSFont *font = [NSFont fontWithName:fontName size:12.0f];
[self.textView.textStorage addAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}
  range:selection];
```

Depending on the contents of your `NSPopUpButton` it should be enough to call `fontWithName:size:` with `title` as the font name to get the just selected font. But if the method you already do doesn’t work, you’ll probably have to get a specific font from the font family name. `availableMembersOfFontFamily:` on `NSFontManager` will give you a list of all available fonts. You can use one of them to initialize a specific font.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`setFont:range:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSText/setFont%3arange%3a) method on `NSText`, the superclass of `NSTextView`.

(The ranges, of course, come from the [`selectedRanges`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextView/selectedRanges) property on `NSTextView`.)

Answer (score 0):

This was all I needed to change all the text in my textview.

```
[textview setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:14]];
```